# problem running the "load more" button and displaying the new informations above the old informations

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I try to create a "load more" button for messaging page.
I want to place the "load more" button on top of the new messages and when I press button older messages to load on top of new messages, but when I click on load more button, new messages go under the old messages.
how can I do that? like number 2 in this image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9uxF.png)

index.php :

```
<button id="btn2" >load more</button>

<div  id="comnts2" style="padding: 3px"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var comnco2 = 2;
    var page_num2 = 2;
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "lmsg.php",
        data: { comnco2: comnco2 }
      })
      .done(function(msg2) {
    if(msg2 == ' '){
          $("#btn2").hide();
        } else {
       $("#comnts2").append(msg2);
        }
      });
      comnco2 = comnco2 + page_num2;
  });

  $("#btn2").trigger("click");

});
</script>
```

and this is lmsg.php

```
$comnco2=$_POST['comnco2'];

$q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM t_msg WHERE id >
((SELECT MAX(id) FROM t_users) - '$comnco2')  LIMIT 0, 2");
while($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
echo $f['id']."<br>";
}?>
-------<br>
```

thanks

Comment: I'm learning it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$("#comnts2").append(msg2);
```

to

```
$("#comnts2").prepend(msg2);
```